# python yaml logging - how to create log files within a folder

Tags: python, yaml

My project structure is

```
project 
   |
   |---------src
   |          |
   |          |---------logging.py
   |          
   |--------logs.yaml
```

```
#logs.yaml

  version: 1
  formatters:
    simple:
      format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  handlers:
    console:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: simple
      stream: ext://sys.stdout
    info_file_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: INFO
      formatter: simple
      filename: /tmp/info.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8
    error_file_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: ERROR
      formatter: simple
      filename: /tmp/errors.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8
    missed_eopatch_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: WARNING
      formatter: simple
      filename: /tmp/eopatch_warnings.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8
  loggers:
    missed_eopatch:
      level: WARNING
      handlers: [missed_eopatch_handler, console]
      propagate: no
  root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler, missed_eopatch_handler]
```

```
#logging.py

with open('../logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
    log_cfg = yaml.safe_load(f.read())

logging.config.dictConfig(log_cfg)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This doesn't seem to generate any files within `tmp` folder. I created `tmp` folder within `project` folder or `src` folder but no log files are created inside `tmp` folder. If I don't give `tmp` folder then the log files are created inside `src` folder. I want to create log files under `project/tmp` folder

Comment: From your configuration seems the logs should be under /tmp. If you want to dynamically get the tmp under your project's directory, you can assign a 'filename' after you load your logging yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

you probably created log file in system's tmp folder. relative directory `../tmp` should work

Answer (score 0):

Take 'error_file_handler' as an example. Assume your configuration is this way. The only difference is leading slash of filename removed.

```
    error_file_handler:
      class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
      level: ERROR
      formatter: simple
      filename: tmp/errors.log
      maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
      backupCount: 20
      encoding: utf8
```

Here is the code to handle this:

```
import os
    
def get_root_dir():
    import __main__ as main
    if main:
        if hasattr(main, '__file__'):
            script_name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), main.__file__))
            script_dir = os.path.dirname(script_name)
        else:
            script_dir = os.getcwd()
    else:
        script_dir = os.getcwd()
    return script_dir
    
#logging.py

with open('../logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
    log_cfg = yaml.safe_load(f.read())

log_name = os.path.join(get_root_dir(), log_cfg['handlers']['error_file_handler']['filename'])
log_cfg['handlers']['error_file_handler']['filename'] = log_name

logging.config.dictConfig(log_cfg)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```